# how to add custom validaton array file in lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

we have resources/lang directory in laravel so we can add our language directory in that and add validation.php and use that for translation of validation error messages 
but that does not exist in lumen , so how we can add our array of whole custom validation messages to auto use by laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so, add your messages to custom array in the  resources/lang/xx/validation.php language file.

Add custom email validation message :

```
'custom' => [
    'email' => [
        'required' => 'We need to know your e-mail address!',
    ],
],
```

Check lumen validation docs :https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation